# C# Polymorphic models with NSwag

Tags: c#, polymorphism, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5, nswag

Within my Asp.Net Core v5 application we have the following models

```
public class StorageRecordTypeMetadataBase
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
}

public class StringRecordTypeMetadata: StorageRecordTypeMetadataBase
{
    public string? ValidationRegex { get; set; }
}

public class NumericRecordTypeMetadata : StorageRecordTypeMetadataBase
{
    public int MinValue { get; set; }
    public int MaxValue { get; set; }
}
```

In my application `Startup.cs` I have registered Swagger and NSwag setup as following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSwaggerDocument();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseOpenApi();
        app.UseSwaggerUi3();
     }

}
```

In order to support polymorphism, I have followed the guideline as written by NSwag creator: [Guide on inheritance in NSwag](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/wiki/Inheritance), and here is how my model looks like updated:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonInheritanceConverter), "discriminator")]
[KnownType(typeof(StringRecordTypeMetadata))]
[KnownType(typeof(NumericRecordTypeMetadata))]
public class StorageRecordTypeMetadataBase
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
}
```

As soon as I run the application, swagger fails as swagger.json could not be generated. Upon investigating the issue I can see the following error message once I try to manually navigate to /swagger/v1/swagger.json

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.String
> Namotion.Reflection.XmlDocsExtensions.GetXmlDocsSummary(System.Reflection.MemberInfo)'.
> at
> NSwag.Generation.Processors.OperationSummaryAndDescriptionProcessor.ProcessSummary(OperationProcessorContext
> context, List`1 attributes)    at NSwag.Generation.Processors.OperationSummaryAndDescriptionProcessor.Process(OperationProcessorContext context)    at NSwag.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreOpenApiDocumentGenerator.RunOperationProcessors(OpenApiDocument document, ApiDescription apiDescription, Type controllerType, MethodInfo methodInfo, OpenApiOperationDescription operationDescription, List`1 allOperations, OpenApiDocumentGenerator
> swaggerGenerator, OpenApiSchemaResolver schemaResolver)    at
> NSwag.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreOpenApiDocumentGenerator.AddOperationDescriptionsToDocument(OpenApiDocument
> document, Type controllerType, List`1 operations, OpenApiDocumentGenerator swaggerGenerator, OpenApiSchemaResolver schemaResolver)    at NSwag.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreOpenApiDocumentGenerator.GenerateForControllers(OpenApiDocument document, IGrouping`2[] apiGroups, OpenApiSchemaResolver
> schemaResolver)    at
> NSwag.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreOpenApiDocumentGenerator.GenerateAsync(ApiDescriptionGroupCollection
> apiDescriptionGroups)    at
> NSwag.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreOpenApiDocumentGenerator.GenerateAsync(Object
> serviceProvider)    at
> NSwag.AspNetCore.OpenApiDocumentProvider.GenerateAsync(String
> documentName)    at
> NSwag.AspNetCore.Middlewares.OpenApiDocumentMiddleware.GenerateDocumentAsync(HttpContext
> context)    at
> NSwag.AspNetCore.Middlewares.OpenApiDocumentMiddleware.GetDocumentAsync(HttpContext
> context)    at
> NSwag.AspNetCore.Middlewares.OpenApiDocumentMiddleware.GetDocumentAsync(HttpContext
> context)    at
> NSwag.AspNetCore.Middlewares.OpenApiDocumentMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

I have tried to include the referenced package **Namotion.Reflection** even myself but that did not help either. Is there anything that I have missed during my configuration?

This was supposed to add `discriminator` field within the base model so that it would be automatically recognized when I generate my models on front end (React) side. I can achieve this behavior by moving away from NSwag, to Swashbuckle like following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
       {
           c.UseAllOfForInheritance();
           c.SelectSubTypesUsing(baseType =>
           {
               return typeof(StorageRecordType).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(baseType));
           });

           c.SelectDiscriminatorNameUsing((baseType) => "itemType");
           c.SelectDiscriminatorValueUsing((subType) => subType.Name);
       });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger((SwaggerOptions c) => { });
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
     }

}
```

However this completely breaks the NSwag generation process on my React side. Methods from all controllers are put together into a single Client (instead of being separated per controller name), plus some of the classes required in the parameters seem to be gone as well.

How can I fix the NSwag in order to get the discriminator value in my swagger.json response?

Comment: Is this really a polymorphism issue? Did already try simplifying your models temporarily? Maybe you can narrow down the problem that way.

Comment: Models have been simplified for this case. In reality we have more sub-types that inherit from the base class with their own set on unique properties. Therefore merging them into one huge class does not seem ideal from our perspective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so the issue was, that I was using older version of `Nswag.AspNetCore`. Instead of version `13.10.8` I upgraded to `13.15.5`, which works great with package `NJsonSchema v 10.6.6`